# scroll to bottom not working chatwindow ionic

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a chat page in my app where the chat-div is inside a wrapper-div. The structure looks like this:

```
<ion-content>
 <div class="wrapper>
 <div class="chatwindow">
 <ion-grid>
 <ion-row *ngFor="let message of messages">
 <ion-col *ngIf="message.fromId !== myUid>
 <div class="message other-message>
 <span>{{message.text}}</span>
 </div>
 </ion-col>
 <ion-col *ngIf="message.fromId === myUid>
 <div class="message my-message>
 <span>{{message.text}}</span>
 </div>
 </ion-col>
 </ion-row>
 </ion-grid>
 </div>
 </div
</ion-content>
```

My problem is that I am not able to make the chatpage scroll to bottom (both at pageload and when new messages arrives).

What I have tried so far:
TS: file

```
import {IonContent} from '@ionic/angular';

@ViewChild(‘content’) content: IonContent;

ngOninit(){
setTimeout(()=>{this.content.scrollToBottom();},200);
}
```

HTML file:

```
<ion-content #content>
```

Above does not give any effect, i also tried using ngZone and `[scrollEvents=“true”]`.

The only thing that has given some effect is `[ScrollTop]=“content.scrollheight”`. But then the whole chatpage reloades everytime a message arrives and it scroll up and down very fast.

Any help with this will be much appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: check your ViewChild: it should be like `@ViewChild(Content) content: Content;`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It still doesnt work unfortunately. However, my bad - I noticed that I have to use IonContent instead else i cant find the method scrollToBottom() so i edited my question if that could be helpful!